# In regards TFS backlogs not copied when restored to different server

Tags: tfs-2015

I have restored TFS from production to non production environment. The database restored Tfs_Configuration, Tfs_Warehouse, Tfs_ProjectCollection. Everything seems to work as expected. I access TFS non production via URL and navigate to Backlog and i can't find any records of previous backlogs let say November, it only display list of the dates under Past header and no entries. But if i click Stories and Backlog with selecting any dates that the work items are displayed. It similar thing if i choose Features. Is this expected?

I am using TFS 2015 Update 3

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you do exactly following the steps mentioned in below article to restore the DBs.

[Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware#refresh-the-data-cache-on-client-computers)

You can try to [Refresh the data cache on client computers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware#refresh-caches-clients)

Besides you probably need to go delete the cache on your application tier as well because you don’t want it to be out of sync with the database you just restored.